# How to get schema from confluent schema registry with schema id and version using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

Can we pass both schema id and version to get the schema from schema registry? I know about these functions,

Getting schema by ID

```
sr = SchemaRegistryClient('localhost:8081')
my_schema = sr.get_by_id(schema_id=1)
```

which returns,

`{'type': 'record', 'name': 'io.confluent.examples.clients.basicavro.Customer', 'fields': [{'name': 'customerId', 'type': 'string'}, {'name': 'firstName', 'type': 'int'}, {'name': 'lastName', 'type': 'string'}, {'name': 'email', 'type': 'string'}, {'name': 'phone', 'type': 'string'}], '__fastavro_parsed': True}`

And,

Getting schema by subject name

```
sr = SchemaRegistryClient('localhost:8081')
my_schema = sr.get_schema(subject='mySubject', version='latest')
```

which returns,

```
SchemaVersion(subject='mySubject', schema_id=1, schema=<schema_registry.client.schema.AvroSchema object at 0x000001A7271D6C18>, version=1)
```

In get_schema() I am able to give the version but schema is not proper. In get_by_id() I am getting the schema in proper format but not able to choose the version.

Is there any way around so I can get the schema and choose the version also? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track, but you need to use fields in that returned class

```
version = 1
schema_version = sr.get_schema(subject='mySubject', version=version)

print(schema_version.schema)
print(schema_version.version == version)
```